# checkbox not shown as checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in html

```
 <div class="ft_ck_area" id="fromFirstHalf">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="fromFirstHalfChk" name="fromChkValue" value="1"/>
                            <label for="fromFirstHalfChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">First Half</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="ft_ck_area"  id="fromSecondHalf">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="fromSecondHalfChk" name="fromChkValue" value="2"/>
                            <label for="fromSecondHalfChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">Second Half</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ft_ck_area" id="fromFullDay">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="fromFullDayChk" name="fromChkValue" value="0"/>
                            <label for="fromFullDayChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">Full Day</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



<div class="ft_ck_area" id="toFirstHalf">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="toFirstHalfChk" name="toChkValue"  value="1"/>
                            <label for="toFirstHalfChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">First Half</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ft_ck_area" id="toSecondHalf">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="toSecondHalfChk"  name="toChkValue" value="2"/>
                            <label for="toSecondHalfChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">Second Half</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ft_ck_area" id="toFullDay">
                        <div class="cb">
                            <input type="radio" class="css-checkbox" id="toFullDayChk" name="toChkValue" value="0"/>
                            <label for="toFullDayChk" name="checkbox1_lbl" class="css-label">Full Day</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in javascript i am doing following code after checked attribute is removed from checkbox it is appended in html if i see it in html but it is not shown as checked,

```
       if (dateDiff == 0) {
                var fromCheckedId=$('input[name=fromChkValue]:checked').attr("id");
                $("#"+fromCheckedId).removeAttr("checked");
                console.log("1");
                console.log("#"+fromCheckedId);
                var toCheckedId=$('input[name=toChkValue]:checked').attr("id");
                $("#"+toCheckedId).removeAttr("checked");
                console.log("2");
                console.log("#"+toCheckedId);
                $("#fromFullDayChk").attr("checked","checked");
                }
                else
                {
                    var fromCheckedId=$('input[name=fromChkValue]:checked').attr("id");
                $("#"+fromCheckedId).removeAttr("checked");
                console.log("3");
                console.log("#"+fromCheckedId);
                var toCheckedId=$('input[name=toChkValue]:checked').attr("id");
                $("#"+toCheckedId).removeAttr("checked");
                console.log("4");
                console.log("#"+toCheckedId);
                $("#fromFullDayChk").attr("checked","checked");
                $("#toFullDayChk").attr("checked","checked");
                }
```

what is wrong in this code? after attribute is removed then againe i have appended attribute

Comment: Which Jquery version used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
  $("#fromFullDayChk").attr("checked",true);
```

Instead of

```
$("#fromFullDayChk").attr("checked","checked");
```

If you are using latest version of Jquery then use `prop` as below:

```
$("#fromFullDayChk").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Using `prop()` instead would be a better suggestion.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It is depend on Jquery version

Comment: Questioner says they're using 1.11.1.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (because you are using `Jquery 1.11.1`) :

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property
>   values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause
>   inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method
>   provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values.

**Explanation**  -

> selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType,
>   ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved
>   and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties
>   were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the
>   scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties.

So, you should use .prop():

For Check :-

```
$("#fromFullDayChk").prop("checked",true);
```

Un-Check :-

```
$("#fromFullDayChk").prop("checked",false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript way :

```
// check
document.getElementById("yourCheckboxId").checked = true;

//  uncheck
document.getElementById("yourCheckboxId").checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

`$("#fromFullDayChk").attr("checked",true);`